# OpenGL performance on laptop's external monitor

Tags: performance, opengl, external, monitor

I'm writing a small viewer application on Windows using C++ and OpenGL (Glfw).

I've struggled to get a consistent framerate @ 60fps with no or almost no drop frames and so far so good. But, the application must be able to run on different monitors, ie either on the laptop's own display or an external one. I'm running on a Lenovo P50 and a full HD external monitor.

Running in duplicate mode everything is fine, while in extended mode using the external display I get many drop frames. I have tested this on other systems as well and it's the same pattern: the external monitor in *extended* mode is having a lot of frame drops.

Is this as expected?

Comment: I assume you got just single gfx card for this so my guesses are: 1. HDMI or DVI or VGA ?  Has smaller resolution any impact? may be you are stretching bandwidth to the limit. 2. Another option is double Sync collide with time frame try to turn of one or both monitors sync.

Comment: Running on HDMI. Smaller resolution doesn't change anything. Tried 720p, 800x600, 640x480. Fiddling with the vsync settings, tried both programatically and in the driver, hasn't given anything.

Comment: hmm than it has nothing to do with sync blocking nor bandwidth So most likely your gfx chip can not handle 2 different feeds at the same time.

Comment: one last thing to try set one monitor to 60Hz and the other to something else like 72Hz or whatever. if the behavior is better than your chip  is sync blocking internally regardless on the settings (possibly due to usage of the same clock source somewhere but that i spure speculation from my side).

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I'll try that. Thx.